# "is" or "are" after "one Z of "

Tags: grammatical-number

When writing *"One application of X is/are Y"* and X is singular and Y is plural, is it *is* or *are* then?  And why?

(Phrasing it the other way round would be easy: *Y are one application of X*)

Example: One application of data science *is/are* classification systems.

Comment: Isn't "one application" singular?

Comment: @KillingTime yes it is. What do you want to say with that?

Comment: Therefore your 'Y are' is obviously wrong.

Comment: Now parse *Classification systems are one application of data science*!

Comment: Hey guys, I am not a native speaker and would really like to understand the logic behind this. So @KateBunting you are saying my "rephrasing" "Y are..." is wrong as well? This is not obvious to me but rather confuses me even more. And HighPerformanceMark what do you mean with "Now parse"?

Comment: The subject always dictates the required verb form; Garner, I think, states that this is almost always A (the first-mentioned) in << A is/are B >> statements with A, B noun phrases. Thus 'Classification systems are one application of data science' and 'One application of data science is classification systems' are acceptable and required. However, the mismatch can still be jarring, and rephrasing usually sounds better: 'Classification systems constitute one application of data science' / 'The creation of classification systems is one application of data science'.

Comment: I meant that, as _one_ is singular, it should obviously be _one application is_. I'm afraid I commented in a hurry and didn't notice that you had said that Y is something plural.